# UPDATE table SET value which SELECT from other table

Tags: sql-server

I need to update the column on `Table_1`, and then `SET` the value which select from `Table_2`

```
UPDATE top(3) a 
SET col_1 = col_2_From_Table_2
// Problem here, select col_2 from Table_2 and update into col_1
FROM Table_1
```

**Table_1**

```
ID  | col_1
-------------
11  | null
11  | null
11  | null
11  | null
11  | null
```

**Table_2**

```
col_2
-----
AA
BB
CC
```

**Expected Result of Table_1** (Update top 3 records which select form `Table_2`)

```
ID | col_1
----------
11  | AA
11  | BB
11  | CC
11  | null
11  | null
```

Comment: Why do you reference table 2 in code but table 3 in your description?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I need both Table_1 and Table_2 to find out which column that need to be updated. And then use the column from Table_3 and update into Table_1.

Comment: I still don't see what table 2 has to do with anything? Does it have rows that aren't in table 1? Is it missing rows from table 1?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Hmm..the original code need the Table_2 to make it work. Anyway, I have removed it since it is not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

So really these tables aren't related in any way at all. Assuming you want each row in table 2 assigned to a row in table 1, here's one arbitrary way to do it:

```
;WITH t1 AS 
(
  SELECT ID, col_1, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col_1)
    FROM dbo.table_1
    WHERE ID = 11 -- guessing here based on sample data
),
t2 AS 
(
  SELECT col_2, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col_2) 
    FROM dbo.table_2
)
UPDATE t1 
    SET col_1 = t2.col_2
  FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN t2 
    ON t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

If you have other columns you want to order by, you can add them. If you only want three rows and there are more than three rows in table 2, add:

```
WHERE t2.rn <= 3;
```